# Not able to create json

Tags: javascript, json

I have values stored in the following variable nad have a json structure. But values are not being stored to json. code given below.

```
var ReportSelected =  [];
var PeopleSelected = [];
var FilterSelected = [];
var summaryJson = {
    "reportselectedjson" :  [],
    "PeopleSelected" : [],
    "FilterSelected" : []
};

for ( var int = 0; int < ReportSelected.length; int++) {
     summaryJson.reportselectedjson.push(ReportSelected[int]);
        }
 for ( var int2 = 0; int2 < PeopleSelected.length; int2++) {
    summaryJson.PeopleSelectedjson.push(PeopleSelected[int2]);
}
 for ( var int3 = 0; int3 < FilterSelected.length; int3++) {
    summaryJson.FilterSelectedjson.push(FilterSelected[int3]);

}
 console.log(JSON.stringify(summaryJson));
```

this gives no value in json.

Comment: `ReportSelected`, `PeopleSelected`, & `FilterSelected` are empty, thus you get `{"reportselectedjson":[],"PeopleSelected":[],"FilterSelected":[]}` in the console.

Comment: All your 'Selected' arrays are empty, so their length is 0, thus none of the for loops actually go into the push statement. There needs to be items inside the ReportSelected, etc. arrays.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to loop through the array when you can just reference it....

Answer (score 0):

your PeopleSelected, ReportSelected and FilterSelected arrays are all empty. so you will not get anything in the summaryJson.

Answer (score 0):

yes, everyone has picked up the problem. The arrays are empty... here's a slightly edited version of your code;

```
var ReportSelected = ['one','two','three'],
    PeopleSelected = ['test1','test2','test3'],
    FilterSelected = ['filt1','filt2','filt3'], 
    summaryJson = { 
        "Reportselectedjson" : [], 
        "PeopleSelectedjson" : [], 
        "FilterSelectedjson" : [] 
    };

for ( var int = 0; int < ReportSelected.length; int++) {
     summaryJson.Reportselectedjson.push(ReportSelected[int]);
}

for ( var int2 = 0; int2 < PeopleSelected.length; int2++) {
    summaryJson.PeopleSelectedjson.push(PeopleSelected[int2]);
}

for ( var int3 = 0; int3 < FilterSelected.length; int3++) {
    summaryJson.FilterSelectedjson.push(FilterSelected[int3]);

}

alert(JSON.stringify(summaryJson));
```

A here's the JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/3xajv687/